# gmail email relay work around or alternatives

Tags: email, singleemailmessage

I was wondering what other organizations using gmail have done for email relaying with Salesforce.  My organization will not be removing the gmail authentication so I was wondering if there is a work around, or if other organizations are using another service to be able to send emails from Salesforce without the "via" link.

I'm looking into AWS Simple email Service (SES) and send grid to send our one-off transactional emails.  I would like to hear what others have done to get around this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: @pchittum
We are looking for similar solutions but no luck. We used Google authentication to log in users to Community cloud website and then send a mass email within Community, by selecting the readymade email templates. Now, we need to avoid using Google (since the userbase has increased/cost), we want to substitute Google for sending an email. Any workable solution that someone shares? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using they paid version of Google Apps you can use it as your email relay at no costs - gone is the "via" message. Find the detailed instructions here: http://www.grooveapp.com/blog/salesforce-remove-via-gmail/

Cheers