# send mass emails from Salesforce using personal emails

Tags: rest-api, email, controller, authentication, custom-controller

We have users who will trigger mass emails to generated leads, child users as a part of their campaign. Till date, it is done using google and we are planning to remove gsuite from our system. When we are searching for the alternatives, we came across several smtp services such as sendgrid, Amazon SES, MassMailer, etc. Of these sendgrid and Amazon SES seems to be more cheaper than  MassMailer.

The catch here is, users want to send their campaigns using their personal email Ids. As we are using google, we need not worry about that as the users can send through their gmail. But now, as we are opting out gsuite, we are in dilemma on how to implement this functionality of sending emails using personal email IDs. 
When we approached Amazon SES, they said that we need to own the domain that we want to authenticate. Same goes for SendGrid as well.

Is there any other way or smtp service that allows us to authenticate domains of our choice and send emails from salesforce using user's personal emails. Please suggest

I have gone through the similar post in stack exchange [gmail email relay work around or alternatives](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29011/gmail-email-relay-work-around-or-alternatives?rq=1) and now please dont spam me for duplicate post. I'm here to get latest solution as this thread might have expired

Comment: Have you researched other email delivery services like Mandrill, SparkPost, etc?

Comment: Yes I did. It is similar to sendgrid as we need to use middleware like Zapier to integrate with Salesforce. We need something like amazon SES where we can use their SMTP interface to trigger outbound emails and on the other hand we need to use any domain of our choice to send these emails. Please suggest any possibilities